# How to append parenthesis to the string text in python?

Tags: python

I have one string like "Article created on March 03 2021 for the some user"

I want to convert that string to "Article created on (March 03 2021 for the some user)" so I thought I should create a list containing all the name of the months, and then scan the string and if any month found then it should add starting parenthesis "(" to the left of the month's name and another closing parenthesis ")" at the end of the string.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You seem to have an idea how to solve the problem already, what happens when you start writing code to do it? Can you show us what you have so far? With only one example, I'm not sure how much general advice we can give you. Is the date (and user name) the only thing that can change in the string? Then it's probably easiest to chop off the "Article created on " prefix just by slicing past it, rather than parsing the date. But if that part can change too, it's a much more challenging problem.

Comment: Please don't tag with JavaScript after you have asked for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `re.sub` here:

```py
inp = "Article created on March 03 2021 for the some user"
output = re.sub(r'(\w+ \d{2} \d{4}\b.*)', r'(\1)', inp)
print(output)  # Article created on (March 03 2021 for the some user)
```

Comment: How can I do this with javascript ?

Comment: You tagged this question for Python.  If you need help with JavaScript you should open a new question.

Comment: @ujjwalkpatel In JS use something like: `input.replace(/(\w+ \d{2} \d{4}\b.*)/, "($1)")`

Answer (score 0):

Writing code by your logic, initialize a `list` of months

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

Now iterate over all the words in the string and check if that word is in the `months` list.

```
newLine = ""
for word in line.split():
    if word in months:
        newLine += "("

    newLine += word + " "
```

Now at the end, remove the trailing space and append the closing bracket

```
newLine = newLine[:-1]
newLine += ")"
```